# Получение списка неизвестных ключей json

Tags: java, json, валидация, deserialize

Коллеги! Есть задача: На вход API подается объект String (json). В этом json могут быть ключи,поля,которые принадлежат данному объекту ,но могут быть и невалидные поля. Пример:

```
{
"name": "name#1",
"address": "address#1",
"pone": "000000000",
"ail": "mail@smth.ru",
"additional"{
"wrong": 324
 }
}
```

где поля 'ail','pone' - не существуют в главном объекте,'additional.wrong'-ошибочен по типу данных. Данных ключей с таким типом/неймом нет в объектах (в главном/вложенном). Необходимо собрать все эти невалидные поля в список при десериализации с помощью ObjectMapper (jackson) с условием,что стоит флаг TRUE на FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES.

Было найдено рабочее решение,которое подразумевает в каждом объекте (даже во вложенных) добавление допом мапы(get + set), использование аннотаций @JsonAnyGetter & @JsonAnySetter и флаг FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES= false. Но каждый раз поднимать у каждого объекта эту мапу и проверять на размерность + формировать информацию (при условии,что сам вложенный объект !=null) - слишком трудоемко, учитывая ,что дается большой главный объект со множеством вложенных объектов.

Есть ли возможность как-то настроить mapper или правильно переопределить метод deserialize? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Спасибо!

Comment: То есть вы хотите переопределить всю десериализацию, чтобы отлавливать 'UnrecognizedPropertyException'?  Не совсем понятно, на каком уровне должен тогда существовать список, в котором хранятся неизвестные поля.

Comment: В моем проекте используется кваркус и ошибка падает в: org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:64) где и формируется конечный вывод ошибки , хотя используется везде jackson. Полагаю, что внутри отлавливается 'UnrecognizedPropertyException'. Поэтому,если это возможно,то хотелось бы начать с отловки 'UnrecognizedPropertyException'.

Comment: Просто интересно: каким образом пропадают буквы "mail" -> "ail", "phone" -> "pone"? Может быть может помочь [проверка JSON схемы](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java)?

Comment: Неправильно вводит пользователь.Тут сложно понять причину,но я пыталась использовать json схему. Безуспешно. Не выдает ошибок вообще (что странно)